# Serialize with java 7, deserialize with java 6?

Tags: java, serialization, jvm, deserialization, java-7

Any idea if standard (default) serialization with java 7 should be read (deserialize) with java 6?

Answer (score 4):

It can be read provided you don't serialise any classes added in Java 7. i.e. you still need every class used on the receiving end.

BTW There were incompatible changes made between Java 1.3 and 1.4 AFAIK.  You should be ok back to Java 1.4.

Comment: Also assuming that the classes haven't changed, right? Assuming the JDK follows Java's own convention, checking that the serialVersionUid is the same between the version should be enough.

Comment: It is possible to handle changes with some care but that's not really a Java 6 vs 7 issue. ;)